# How to correct configure beans in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, dependency-management

I faced with a problem of beans configuration in spring boot. In other words:
I have 3 microservices (utils, orders, admin). Utils for utility classes, orders for book orders, admin for administrate something. Orders and Admin have as a dependency Utils module. In Utils I have class that used in Orders, but not in the Admin module, but the Admin module has dependency on Utils because it used other utility classes. Back to orders :) Orders used class from Utils for example Payment that has Autowired RestTemplate and RestTemplate need Configuration. Some code below for understanding ...

```
@Import({
RestTemplateConfig.class})
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.test")
public class OrdersApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OrdersApp.class, args);
    }
}

    @Import({
    RestTemplateConfig.class})
    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.test")
    public class AdminApp {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(OrdersApp.class, args);
        }
    }

public class Payment{

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
}

public Payment(
            RestTemplate restTemplate
    ) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

@EnableConfigurationProperties({RestTemplateConfigProperties.class})
public class RestTemplateConfig {

    @Bean("restTemplate")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder, RestTemplateConfigProperties configProperties) {
        return builder
                .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(configProperties.getConnectTimeoutSec()))
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(configProperties.getReadTimeoutSec()))
                .build();
    }
}
```

BUT

In AdminApp I don't use Payment class that has autowired rest template that need configuration and I don't need to Import RestTemplateConfig.class for AdminApp, but AdminApp has dependency in pom.xml on Utils that has Payment that has restTemplate that need configuratuion (LOL)

How I cant improve confirations and bean init for this situation

Comment: What you mean by *improve*? What don't you like?

Comment: @mentallurg, I won't import RestTemplateConfig where I don't use service method that needs this config